# How to find unique IDs?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

On the indeed job site and inspecting an element over a job, each job is listed as i.e. `<a id="saj0"` next job would be `id="saj1"` and so forth.

Now to get the first job title, I have the below code, but what I would like to know is how do I change just the last character +1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

val1 = input("Enter Job: ")
val2 = input("Enter Location: ")

url = "https://www.indeed.co.uk/jobs?q={}&l={}".format(val1, val2)
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

result1 = soup.find(id="sja0")
print(result1.text)
```

Comment: Please share an example of the `input`’s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `find_all` function to get more than one item, then use a regex.

```py
import re

tags_a = soup.find_all(id=re.compile(r"sja\d+"))
for tag_a in tags_a:
    print(tag_a.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a loop. Based on your post, I'm assuming you haven't done much programming at all. You should probably start with a Python tutorial.

I would avoid using the id tag; they are typically dynamically generated and can change from one visit to another. They don't give you a lot of flexibility either since an `id` should only appear once on a page. Look at the `class` attribute. You may want to look over an HTML tutorial as well.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

val1 = input("Enter Job: ")
val2 = input("Enter Location: ")

url = "https://www.indeed.co.uk/jobs?q={}&l={}".format(val1, val2)
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# Find all the clickcards on the page
cards = soup.find_all(class_="clickcard")

# Print the titles of the cards
for card in cards:
    print(card.find("h2").contents)
```

Comment: Cheers for the reply, yeah I ended up using a loop anyway.  On the indeed job site all jobs have a seperate ID.  Thanks for the reply